# Change H3 colour onClick and then Fade Back

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I've got a button on the top of my page that scrolls to a DIV when I click it, but I also want it to make that h3 flash to one colour and then back to original when it has scrolled to it like Facebook does for notifications.

JQuery so far:

```
        function goToByScroll(id) {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top }, 'slow');
        $("#" + id).css({ "color": "yellow" }).delay(1000).css({ "color": "#222" });
    }
```

HTML so far:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('createdest')">Add Destination</a>

<h3 id="createdest">Add a Country</h3>
```

But so far nothing is changing. What can I try next?

Comment: Whoops. I pulled the wrong H3 to put here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `animate()` function's callback to run the code right after the animation completes.

Also, I added `data` attributes to store the original color of the element:

```
var $target = $("#" + id);
$target.data('oldColor', $target.css("color"));
$target.css("color", "yellow");

$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top }, 'slow', function() {
  $target.delay(1000).css('color', $target.data('oldColor'))
});
```

Comment: is that all of it? It didn't run at all?

Answer (score 2):

try `queue()` method:

```
   function goToByScroll(id) {
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top }, 'slow');
            $("#" + id).css({ "color": "yellow" }).delay(1000).queue(function() {
              $(this).css({ "color": "#222" });
   })
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. However you missed a `}` :)
My only problem is it changes before it even gets there, so if possible could I make it change once it's there? Also if I click a second time the colour doesn't change again. It just stays yellow